# OleDbConnection: how do I determine if it is an HTML (Web Page) document or Excel document

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledbconnection

I have program, which parses Excel documents and binds it to GridView in asp.net using **OleDbConnection**.

```
connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0; HDR=NO;\";", filePath);
```

Also it has an option to parse Web Page with `OleDbConnection`, but in case where importing document is a Web Page it throws exception "**External table is not in right format**" or kind of.

```
connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"HTML Import; IMEX=1;\";", filePath);
```

This connection string is good for Web Page. if you try parse Excel document it will provide you the same exception (see above).

So how could I determine which type of file I get, when all of them have same extension (.xls or .xlsx)? 
So in first case I will use one connection string, in second case - another connection string.

Comment: Try first one in try/catch block - if it throws an exception - try the second one.

Comment: I implemented it so. Can I hope for better one?

Comment: `Html` is plain text, you can use a `StreamReader` to read a chunk and test if it has some expected html tags like `<html>` or `<table>`